# Hibernate QuerySyntaxException Table is not mapped

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

When I try to create any query to database with Hibernate, 
i get the same error:
[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amLUV.png)

DaoMethod:

```
@Override
public List findAll() {
    openCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
    List books = currentSession.createQuery("from AuthorEntity").list();
    closeCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
    return books;
}
```

AuthorEntity(Setters and hashcode&equals are present but hidden):

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class AuthorEntity {
    private long authorId;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "author_id")
    public long getAuthorId() {
        return authorId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Why does this error occur? I do this on IntellijIdea 2018, Java 1.8.
[hibernate.cfg.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Xjr.png)

Comment: Most likely, wrong configuration

Comment: Please post your Hibernate configuration files (hibernate.cfg.xml etc.)

Comment: Please add the configuration to the question body, not as a comment.

Comment: Can you update the whole AuthorEntity class. Just want to see your imports.

Comment: I think you have used "org.hibernate.annotations.Entity" annotation.

Comment: No. I`m using javax.persistence.Entity

Comment: The actual package of AuthorEntity matches the package in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531210/hibernate-exception-table-is-not-mapped

Comment: My files locate in right directories. I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code for your sessionFactory. It helped me

```
final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure().build();
sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
```