# How to use MySql Database queries in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am creating an API by using spring boot. In this project, I used spring web, JPA, jstl and MySql as dependencies of the API. In this project, I have created a Controller, Model and Repository. Basically, this API does CRUD operations. When I use GET request, I want to get only 3 columns. But, the case is I used JPA in this and I don't know how to use custom queries like

> "SELECT devname,hrs,ot FROM imaginaryTable"

.

How can I do this ??

My Controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ImController {

    @Autowired
    private ImRepository TaskRepository;

    @GetMapping("/projects")
    public List<ImModel> findAll() {
        return (List<ImModel>) TaskRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/developers/{id}")
    public ImModel findByName(@PathVariable final int id){
        return TaskRepository.findById(id);
    }

}
```

My Repository interface.

```
package com.kisalka.pacrestapi.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.kisalka.pacrestapi.model.ImModel;

public interface ImRepository extends JpaRepository<ImModel, Integer> {

    ImModel findById(int id);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `@Query("Your query")` annotation inside the repository to query the database. 
For Example

```
@Query(value="SELECT devname,hrs,ot FROM imaginaryTable",nativeQuery=true)
private List<Object> getValues();
```

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: you can get the values, if your return type is 'List<Object>' .I edited my answer based on that. Now you can get the 3 column values.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object by using the columns as parameters for a constructor.

I'll give you an example of my own with a custom DTO I made:

```
@Query("SELECT new org.twinnation.site.dto.TitleAndDescriptionAndId(a.title, a.description, a.id) "
      + "FROM Article a")
List<TitleAndDescriptionAndId> getAllArticlesWithoutContent();
```

Where the DTO `TitleAndDescriptionAndId` is the following:

```
public class TitleAndDescriptionAndId {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Long id;


    public TitleAndDescriptionAndId(String title, String description, Long id) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: In here I have few questions. 
1. ) What did you mean from this letter a ??
2. ) What should I do in the controller ??

Comment: `FROM Article a`. The name of the object/table is `Article`, I just gave it the alias `a`. In your case, you'd write `FROM ImModel im` and use `im` instead of `a`. From the controller, you can just call the method you created using the DTO in your ImRepository.

Comment: It gives me this error - Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ImModel is not mapped [SELECT new Manage(im.pname, im.devname, im.id) FROM ImModel im].. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: you need to include the full path. e.g `com.the.full.package.location.Manage(im.pname, im.devname, im.id)`

Comment: Still, gives me this error - Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ImModel is not mapped [SELECT new com.kisalka.pacrestapi.model.Manage(im.pname, im.devname, im.id) FROM ImModel im]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954590/hibernate-error-querysyntaxexception-users-is-not-mapped-from-users

Answer (score 0):

You could customise the JSON representation of the entity in the Controller by using Spring's support for Jackson's JSONView.

https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#json-views

```
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @GetMapping("/developers/{id}")
    public ImModel findByName(@PathVariable final int id){
        return TaskRepository.findById(id);
    }
```

Alternatively, you could handle at the repository level by using Spring Data's projection functionality:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

```
    @GetMapping("/developers/{id}")
    public ImModelSummaryProjection findByName(@PathVariable final int id){
        return TaskRepository.someMethodReturningSummaryProjection(id);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand this. How can I use "SELECT devname,hrs,ot FROM imaginaryTable" query with this ??

Comment: Did you even read the links? For option 1, simply load the entity **as you are doing** (i.e. no need to write a query) and add the necessary JsonView annotations on your controller, entity fields.

Comment: I tried to use @JsonView(View.Summary.class) in the model class and it gives me this error - View.Summary cannot be resolved to a type. What can I do now ??

Answer (score 0):

As described in Spring Docs: 
**[Interface-based projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)**
The easiest way to limit the result of the queries to expose the name attributes only is by declaring an interface that will expose accessor methods for the properties to be read.

You can create `interface` to limit results

```
interface LimitImaginaryTable {
  String getDevname();
  String getHrs();
  String getOt();
}
```

and then in your `repository` you can use that interface to get limited results

```
public interface ImRepository extends JpaRepository<ImModel, Integer> {

    ImModel findById(int id);
    LimitImaginaryTable findById(int id);
    List<LimitImaginaryTable> findByDevname(String name);

}
```

Now you can simply get the desired resultset in `Controller`

```
List<LimitImaginaryTable> myList = taskRepository.findByDevname("JavaDev");
```

Comment: Okay, this worked perfectly.. But, I want to get only 3 columns as of all the Developers. In this case, I don't want to provide a name in controller. How can I do it ??

Comment: Then you can simply create on more method in your repository `List<LimitImaginaryTable> findAll() ;`and call it in controller `List<LimitImaginaryTable> myList = taskRepository.findAll();`

Comment: Now I get all the data again from Db.. How can I fix this ??

Comment: @Amithash make sure you use the `LimitImaginaryTable` in your list `List<LimitImaginaryTable> myList = taskRepository.findAll();`

Comment: Yes, I used List<LimitImaginaryTable> myList = taskRepository.findAll(); in my controller. But, it gives me all the data.. Can't I Fix this ??