# How to fix Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am creating an API by using spring boot. In this project, I used spring web, JPA, jstl and MySql as dependencies of the API. In this project, I have created a Controller, Model and Repository. Basically, this API does CRUD operations. And also I created a client that consumes my own API. When I use Postman to POST data, it successfully insert data to the database and gives me 200 OK code. Then I created web page and created a html form and used Ajax to get that data. But the thing is when I click insert button in the form, it gives me this error.

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Tue May 01 05:16:48 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'POST' not
>   supported

How can I fix this ??

My controller:

```
package com.kisalka.pacrestapi.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.kisalka.pacrestapi.repository.ImRepository;
import com.kisalka.pacrestapi.model.ImModel;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ImController {

    @Autowired
    private ImRepository TaskRepository;


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/tasks")
    public ImModel createNote(@RequestBody ImModel note) {
        return TaskRepository.save(note);
    }

}
```

My web page:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Project Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname" id="txtPname"/>
                        </div>              
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Developer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="devname" id="txtDevname"/>
                        </div>              
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="btnRegister"/>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

jQuery and Ajax part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Save the new user details
            $('#btnRegister').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/tasks',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        pname: $('#txtPname').val(),
                        devname: $('#txtDevname').val()
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Inserted"); 
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR) {
                        $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#divError').show('fade');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why do you have both a form with a submit button and an ajax request? Odds are the form is being submitted first, which means that the request is being send to "", which would explain why you're getting a `405: Request method 'POST' not supported`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you have both a form with a submit button and an ajax request? Odds are the form is being submitted first, which means that the request is being send to "", which would explain why you're getting a `405: Request method 'POST' not supported`

Try replacing

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
```

for

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/api/tasks">
```

Comment: I tried like this and now I get this error - There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported.. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: @Amithash remove `@RequestBody` from in front of `ImModel note`.

Comment: It works perfectly !! :D Thank You.. If you can, please help with this also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096376/how-to-use-mysql-database-queries-in-spring-boot

Comment: Now I can insert data using form. But, when I use Postman, nothing insert into the database. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: You need to make sure that you have a header row with the key `Content-Type` and the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in Postman

Comment: Can't I use [{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]  as previous ??

Comment: The initial question has already been solved, you should make a different question for that.

Comment: Can I solve this error, without removing @RequestBody ?? When I remove this, I can't use Postman. And also I asked a quiz and no one knows about it..