# JPA Referenced Entities: Is bad practice to reference only its Key instead of all its object

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Suppose the cenário where **customers puts orders** on our system. So, for simplicity, we have 2 entities :

```
Customer
- CustomerID
- Name

Order
- Customer
- OrderID
- OrderValue
```

We have a REST Service that is used to save/update a Customer and also, a REST Service that is used to POST orders.

In JPA, actually, the `Order` entity has a `ManyToOne` relationship to `Customer` entity. So, assuming that I'm not using `DTO`, I need to call my `OrderService` passing, at least, something like this `JSON`:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "customer_id": 10
  },
  "order_id": 40,
  "order_value": 200.1
}
```

And, when I return the order to the RestClient, all `Customer` is being returned, since it's being loaded during the process.

So, thinking on complex systems where the are a lot of Entities that are 'nested', **is it acceptable to (or at least not a bad practice) to create entities that references only the key instead of the object itself**? Something like:

```
Order
- CustomerID
- OrderID
- OrderValue
```

I'm new to JPA/Hibernate and I come from a world where all entities were loaded manually from the Database. So, when dealing with an Order, we used to load only the `Customer.CustomerId` instead of all Customer data. Here, in this example, I think that I have two options: Load all Customer (using FetchType.EAGER or load nothing (using FetchType.LAZY), so, there is no way (at least that I know) to return to the RESTClient an Order object that contais only it's CustomerID (at least, without manually setting order.customer.customer_id manually, thing that sounds a little bit hacky).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes!. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Add the relevant tags to your question e.g. Spring, Spring MVC? Spring Data? so we have a better idea what the options are

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50096610/1356423 for some options on how you can customize the JSON representation of an Entity without the overhead of a full DTO layer.