# Update Password Using Spring Boot and JPA Is Not Working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am developing a web application in which there is a feature to generate the password. I am using Spring Boot + Hibernate + JPA. I am able to use built-in JPA query like `findByUserMobileNumber` etc. But when it is coming to update the password in the database I am getting the error.

Here is my entity class:

```
package gvr.OtpOnWeb.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_users")
public class Users 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PK_AI_unbUserID")
    private int userID;

    @Column(name= "svName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "UQ_svMobileNo")
    private String userMobileNumber;

    @Column(name="svEmailID")
    private String userEmailId;

    @Column(name= "bActiveFlag")
    private int active;

    @Column(name="svPassword")
    private String password;

    public Users() 
    {
        super();
    }

    public Users(int userID, String userName, String userMobileNumber, String userEmailId, int active,
             String password) 
    {
        super();
        this.userID = userID;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userMobileNumber = userMobileNumber;
        this.userEmailId = userEmailId;
        this.active = active;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Users(Users users)
    {
        this.active             = users.getActive();
        this.userEmailId        = users.getUserEmailId();
        this.userName           = users.getUserName();
        this.userMobileNumber   = users.getUserMobileNumber();
        this.password           = users.getPassword();
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserMobileNumber() {
        return userMobileNumber;
    }

    public void setUserMobileNumber(String userMobileNumber) {
        this.userMobileNumber = userMobileNumber;
    }

    public String getUserEmailId() {
        return userEmailId;
    }

    public void setUserEmailId(String userEmailId) {
        this.userEmailId = userEmailId;
    }

    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }       
}
```

Here is repository code:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>, CrudRepository<Users, Integer> {

    Users findByuserMobileNumber(String mobileNumber);

    Users findByuserMobileNumberAndPassword(String mobileNumber, String password);

    @Modifying
    @Query("update tbl_users u set u.svPassword = :password where u.UQ_svMobileNo = :mobilenumber")
    void updateuserPassword(@Param("password") String password, @Param("mobilenumber") String mobilenumber);
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "GeneratePassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView generatePassword(@ModelAttribute(name="generatePasswordForm") Password passwordObj, Model model)
{
    String mobileNumber     = passwordObj.getMobileNumber();
    String enteredPassword  = passwordObj.getPassword();
    String confirmPassword  = passwordObj.getConfirmPassword();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("GeneratePassword");

    logger.info("Entered Mobile Number :"+ mobileNumber);
    logger.info("Entered Password :"+ enteredPassword);
    logger.info("Entered Confirmed Password :"+ confirmPassword);

    userObj = userRepository.findByuserMobileNumber(mobileNumber);
    if(userObj == null)
    {
        logger.info("USER DOES NOT EXIST");
        modelAndView.addObject("messageFromServer", "Mobile Number Is Not Registered");

    }
    else
    {
        logger.info("VALIDATING PASSWORD");
        boolean isEnteredPasswordValid = validationObj.validatePassword(enteredPassword);
        logger.info("IS PASSWORD VALID :"+ isEnteredPasswordValid);
        boolean isConfirmPasswordValid = validationObj.validatePassword(confirmPassword);
        logger.info("IS CONFIRMED PASSWORD VALID :"+ isConfirmPasswordValid);
        boolean arePasswordSame = validationObj.arePasswordSame(enteredPassword, confirmPassword);
        logger.info("ARE BOTH THE PASSWORD SAME :"+ arePasswordSame);
        if(isEnteredPasswordValid == false)
        {
            String messageToSend = "ENTER PASSWORD IN CORRECT FORMAT"; 

            modelAndView.addObject("messageFromServer", messageToSend);
            modelAndView.addObject("mobileNumber", mobileNumber);
            return modelAndView;                
        }
        if(isConfirmPasswordValid == false)
        {
            String messageToSend = "ENTER CONFIRM PASSWORD IN CORRECT FORMAT"; 
            modelAndView.addObject("messageFromServer", messageToSend);
        }
        if(arePasswordSame == false)
        {
            String messageToSend = "PASSWORD MISMATCH ERROR"; 
            modelAndView.addObject("messageFromServer", messageToSend);
            modelAndView.addObject("mobileNumber", mobileNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            // DO FURTHE PROCESSING 
            // ENCRYPT PASSWORD 
            String md5ConfirmedPassword = PasswordHashing.cryptWithMD5(confirmPassword);
            userRepository.updateuserPassword(md5ConfirmedPassword, mobileNumber);
        }            
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Whenever I start my application I get the following list of errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController' defined in file [D:\Development\Eclipse Worspaces\otp_on_web\OtpOnWeb\target\classes\gvr\OtpOnWeb\controller\MainController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void gvr.OtpOnWeb.repository.UserRepository.updateuserPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
at gvr.OtpOnWeb.OtpOnWebApplication.main(OtpOnWebApplication.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void gvr.OtpOnWeb.repository.UserRepository.updateuserPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void gvr.OtpOnWeb.repository.UserRepository.updateuserPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tbl_users is not mapped [update tbl_users u set u.svPassword = :password where u.UQ_svMobileNo = :mobilenumber]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
... 64 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tbl_users is not mapped [update tbl_users u set u.svPassword = :password where u.UQ_svMobileNo = :mobilenumber]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
... 72 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tbl_users is not mapped
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:326)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3706)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3595)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:377)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:269)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
... 78 more
```

What could be the probable error for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate error - QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped \[from users\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954590/hibernate-error-querysyntaxexception-users-is-not-mapped-from-users)

Comment: You should either write valid HQL or tell Spring Data Jpa that it is a native query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this :

```
@Query("update Users u set u.password = :password where u.userMobileNumber = :mobilenumber")
```