# How to create LEFT JOIN with JpaRepository?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables Users and Post.

Entity User looks like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "age")
private int age;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

Entity Post looks like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private  int userId;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

I created UsersRepository with @Query

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
            @Query("SELECT u.id, u.name, u.age FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN post AS p ON u.id=p.user_id WHERE p.user_id IS NULL")
            List<User> findByStatus();
        }
```

I get error `QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped`
Can I do this without @Query? Can i do this with @OneToMany? How can I implement select on Jpa OneToMany?
I want to get all users who don't have posts.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954590/hibernate-error-querysyntaxexception-users-is-not-mapped-from-users). Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Sloved. Adding to entity User    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> freeLUsers; and change query from UserRepository  @Query(value = "SELECT  new kz.nixwins.model.User (l.id, l.name, l.age) FROM User AS l LEFT JOIN Post AS p ON l.id=p.userId WHERE p.userId IS NULL")

Comment: That might work but it's not how you should use Spring Data JPA + Hibernate ORM. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not mapping the association and you are using a native SQL query, instead of a HQL one.

Without changing your `User` entity, you have to use a right join and you should map the association as a [uni-directional many-to-one](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one):

```
@Entity
class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "age")
  private int age;

  ... 
}

@Entity
class Post {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;  

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
  ... 
}
```

Now you can run the following HQL query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM Post p RIGHT JOIN p.user u WHERE p IS NULL");
```

Check the Hibernate ORM documentation for examples of [mapping associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations) and [HQL/JPQL queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql).